How to resolve IFilter from DI in Masstransit
I'm following the Masstransit documentation about creating message type filters but there I see the Filter instance is created manually:
public class ExceptionLoggerSpecification<T> :
    IPipeSpecification<T>
    where T : class, PipeContext
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();
    }

    public void Apply(IPipeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.AddFilter(new ExceptionLoggerFilter<T>());
    }
}

My question is, how can the instantiation be handled by Dependency Injection? For the case the filter has dependencies that need to be resolved.

You should use scoped filters if you want to resolve filters from DI.
Documentation.
